# Chrome extension initiating oauth flow from an origin tab by opening a popup or new tab, redirects to backend and finally returns to the origin tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth

Despite my best efforts and multiple attempts, so far I haven't found a way to have my new tab close and return the origin tab after the user has given permissions to the Oauth window

Here is my code at the moment, it runs in the service worker aka background context and my manifest has the permissions for tabs and system.display

I tried to create myself a new popup window with the chrome API in order to control it and detect change of url so I may catch the redirection call of my backend

This is a failure, since

- the popup does not show on the same screen that browser is
- I get no URL in the logs of my tabs, only pendingURL is set to the URL I gave it, and it never changes

This is what I tried, I expected to get the tab URL, catch the moment it changes to my backend redirect and then close the window I created

I also expected my popup to show on the same page of the browser page I initiated the call

I also tried using window.open before but I didn't manage to control my window then

```ts
export const openPopupWindow = async (
  url: string,
): Promise<chrome.windows.Window> => {
  const popupWidth = 520
  const popupHeight = 520

  const displays = await chrome.system.display.getInfo()

  const primaryDisplay = displays.find((display) => display.isPrimary)
  if (!primaryDisplay) return

  const left = Math.round(
    primaryDisplay.bounds.left + (primaryDisplay.bounds.width - popupWidth) / 2
  )
  const top = Math.round(
    primaryDisplay.bounds.top + (primaryDisplay.bounds.height - popupHeight) / 2
  )


  return new Promise((resolve) =>
    chrome.windows.create(
      {
        type: "popup",
        focused: true,
        width: popupWidth,
        height: popupHeight,
        left,
        top,
        url: url
      },
      (window) => {
        if (window) {
          resolve(window)
        } else {
          resolve(undefined)
        }
      }
    )
  )
}
```

```ts
async function connect(
  authUrl: string,
  successCallback?: SuccessCallback
): Promise<void> {
  const popupWindow = await openPopupWindow(authUrl)

  console.log("FIRST popupWindow", popupWindow)

  const popupInterval = setInterval(async () => {
    try {
      const tab = popupWindow.tabs[0]
      if (popupWindow.tabs.length === 0) {
        // The popup window has been closed
        clearInterval(popupInterval)
        return
      }
      console.log("tab", tab)
      if (tab.url.startsWith("https://localhost")) {
        // The URL has changed to the callback URL
        // Do stuff
          if (successCallback) {
            successCallback()
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error in popupInterval:", error)
    }
  }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: You can use chrome.tabs.onUpdated to detect navigation in the tab.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `Tab` object is static and the `url` property does not automatically update when the `url` changes.

Instead of:

```js
const tab = popupWindow.tabs[0];
if (tab.url.startsWith("https://localhost")) {
```

You could try:

```
chrome.tabs.get(popupWindow.tabs[0].id, (tab) => {
  if (tab.url.startsWith("https://localhost")) {
    // Do something here.
  }
});
```

Fetching the tab again like this should give you an updated URL. Note that this will only happen if you have the `tabs` permission or host permissions for the specific URL.

Also, you may be interested in [chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/identity/#method-launchWebAuthFlow). This handles a lot of the logic you've implemented for detecting redirects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

I used chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow and it works, but I find that the user experience sucks since it opens a new Webview, that forces the user to do an authentication to the Oauth provider, even if the user was already logged in

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Did you give the URL matching change a try?

Comment: Yes it worked out at the end
Thank you for your help :)